# Teradata update target table with source table with multiple ID instances with different dates

Tags: sql-update, teradata

I have two tables A and B.
Table A has has fields such as ID,DATE,AMOUNT etc. ID field has id numbers spanning from 10-15 digit numbers. Some of the numbers are 1 to 4 digit in length and we need to get full digit for these sets. There is another table B that has a ID number details and matches with partial Ids in table A. I need to update table A partial ID with full ID from table B where only few numbers match.

I attempted the following and keep getting an error, please help.

```
Update A
FROM tablenamexyz a,
(select distinct a.ID1,b.ID,date
FROM TABLE tablenamexyz a,
tablenamebty b
where a.ID1=RIGHT(b.ID,4)
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER(OVER(PARTITION BY b.ID ORDER BY date DESC)=1)z
SET a.ID=b.ID
where a.ID1=b.ID1
```

--I keep getting update failed error-7547, Target row update by multiple source rows. You can see in table B, we can just use one source with the latest date. Please help. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: You are partitioning by b.id, but joining on b.id1.  So you potentially have rows in tableb with the same id1 and different id.  Maybe you should be partitioning on id1?

Comment: Your UPDATE WHERE clause should refer to the derived table z not the source table b. And you don't need to pre-join b to a, your "z" can  just remove duplicates from b.

Comment: @ Fred-Had a typo there, the updates is written as a.id=z.id and where a.id=z.id @Andrew-table b's id has multiple instances of the id so we just need 1 source id to update target id in table A.

Answer (score 0):

No need to include table A in your derived table Z, but you *do* need to partition by the value you are going to use in the JOIN (ID1 not ID) for uniqueness:

```
Update A
FROM tablenamexyz a,
(select RIGHT(b.ID,4) as ID_4,b.ID,"date"
FROM tablenamebty b
    QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ID_4 ORDER BY "date" DESC)=1)z
SET a.ID=z.ID
where a.ID1=z.ID_4
```

Note that `date` is a reserved word so if that's really your column name you should quote it.

Comment: Sorry for coming back late on this question, the source ids are duplicates and it did not resolve. Not sure how to handle this issue.

Comment: Does table b have a column named ID1? I have edited the answer to use ID_4 (presumably a unique column name) for the derived join value instead